# Do you know which is this small flower in Asturias?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

Was located in the Turón valley on Mieres, Asturias, Spain (https://goo.gl/maps/BMwyfWtiSdw). Found it at 900 meters of altitude. The plant is just about 8 cm high maybe. All the ones I've found were alone. Just one flower from a couple of leaves.

Kind of reminds me of a Cyclamen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an **Erythronium lily** commonly called a "**dog's-tooth-violet**" or "**trout lily**". I see that one of the species **Erythronium dens-canis** is found in Spain, being native to Europe. Most of the Erythronium species are native to North America. The foliage is very attractive and they are commonly grown as ornimentals. The flower in your photo is just opening. I have included a few links that better describe these lilies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythronium

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythronium_dens-canis

http://www.srgc.org.uk/bulblog/log2008/160108/log.html